# (SOLVED) A limit-definition of derivative computation via Taylor Series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I'd like to calculate the derivative of ln(x) using the limit-definition of derivatives via the Taylor Series representation of ln(x). The end-result is 1/x, for which a Taylor is series defined for |x-1|<1 - but I do not know how to compute it. I'd appreciate any input on how to compute this limit USING TAYLOR SERIES.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This seems more than a little circular.  The Taylor series of a function already represents derivatives *at the point* of expansion for the power series.  Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the power series expansion of $1/x$ around $x=1$, so that you will recognize it.

Comment: The Taylor series expansion _uses_ derivatives at the point of expansion to approximate the function of interest - which becomes exact with infinite terms - it does not 'represent' them. I do not understand your comment.

Comment: Here's an instance where my method yields a sensible result: http://puu.sh/w8Uz8/aa077f7981.png

Comment: A power series does exactly represent an analytic function in a disk of convergence.  The representation is unique for the function and the point of expansion, so it makes sense to *recognize* the Taylor series for $1/x$ around $x=1$.

Comment: I'm not questioning whether taking a derivative of a Taylor series can give sensible results.  It is not so difficult as your calculation makes it out to be, if you know the Taylor series for $\ln (x)$ around $x=1$.  So you might have failed to recognize the success of this approach.

Comment: I see what you're saying now - makes sense. Yet I do not see how this makes my computation any less difficult; am I to use some theorem or computational technique? Is there no way to compute this via algebraic manipulation alone?

Comment: The crucial step involves an *interchange* in the order of limits.  The outer limit is taken to define the derivative as $\Delta x \to 0$ on the difference quotient, while the inner limit is the power series summation.  We need to deal with the justification for pushing the outer limit into the term by term summation, so that a derivative is obtained in the form of a power series.  This is an "algebraic manipulation" but (as with all "infinite" processes) requires a theoretical basis.

Comment: I already solved it. Took a while. Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\ln(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n$, on $|x-1|\leq 1$ (except $x=0$).

You can then do the following :
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(x-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}(x-1)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(x-1)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-x+1)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-(-x+1)}=\frac{1}{x}$$

We used the geometric series here.

Entering the derivative in the series is another theorem of itself. If you must use the differential quotient, I suggest proving the derivative of polynomials first and then using the above method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'proving the derivative of polynomials'? By 'the above method' do you refer to my method or the one you wrote?

Comment: I mean't  if you must use the differential quotient you can use the differential quotient to prove $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$, then use it in the solution I wrote.